# Get class name value on click JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="one two three four">
        <div class=" five">
            <ul>
                <li class="a productOne c"><a class="one two" title="Product One" href="#">Product One</a></li>
                <li class="a productTwo c"><a class="one two" title="Product Two"href="#">Product Two</a></li>
                <li><a class="favourites" title="favourites" href="#">Favourites</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create a click event to capture the product value using Javascript.

I have tried using the code below which will only return the first product:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.Container')
x.querySelectorAll("li")[0].classList[1]
```

How do I create an onclick event to dynamically get the product value? For example, capture "Product One" when first list item is clicked, and create a new variable capturing the product value.

Comment: `var x = document.querySelectorAll('.Container'); x.querySelectorAll("li")[0]` is the same as `document.querySelector(".Container li")`

Comment: What do you mean by product value?

Comment: For example, if I click on list item one, I would like to get the productOne value.

Comment: say I have created var container = document.querySelector(".Container li") and container[0].classList[1] will return productOne. How do I create a click event to return the corresponding product value?

Comment: just one class="Container"

Comment: where is the *product value* in your HTML ? ( there is 2 `title="Product One"` )

Comment: sorry there is a typo. There are two list items. Product One and Product Two

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.Container');
for(var i=0;i<containers.length;i++){
   containers[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      //do things
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand what you trying to do here. In the event listener. where do how do I grab the corresponding value? Using this?

Comment: `e.target` should have everything you need. `e` is a javascript `clickEvent` and `e.target` is a javascript `element `

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `click` events on your container and get the class from the clicked element, like this:

```
document.querySelector('.Container').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.classList[1]);
});
```

But that will capture all clicks inside your container. If you instead want clicks only on your `<li>` tags then you can do it this way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li) => {
    li.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.log(li.classList[1]);
    });
});
```

However, depending on your actual goal there are probably better ways to do this. And the code will throw errors if you click an element with less than two classes.

For example, if you just want to get the product value you could add a custom attribute (say, `data-value`) to your elements with the product value, and then do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[data-value]').forEach((li) => {
    li.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.log(li.getAttribute('data-value'));
    });
});
```

Note that if you add the custom attribute to the anchors instead of the list items you should replace `'li'` with `'a'` in the query selector.

You can check out the last example here: https://jsfiddle.net/onst8myf/

Comment: Thanks! This looks like its working! Is it possible to set the clicked product value? Something like below?

document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
      console.log(li.classList[1]);
      var productVal = li.classList[1]
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create one event listener on your container instead of creating listeners for every `li`/`a` element. This is called [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). You can do it like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('Container')[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    console.log(e.target.title)  
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <div class="one two three four">
        <div class=" five">
            <ul>
                <li class="a productOne c"><a class="one two" title="Product One" href="#">Product One</a></li>
                <li class="a productTwo c"><a class="one two" title="Product One"href="#">Product Two</a></li>
                <li><a class="favourites" title="favourites" href="#">Favourites</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you are clicking on `a` tags. I have updated the answer to work when you click on `a` tag.

Comment: event delegation is a good idea, but your code must also work for a click on both `li` and `a` tag

Comment: You can make it work for any tag. IMHO, the OP's question is not about tags.

Comment: the OP question is is poorly constructed, this can't be a reference